# What does prevent viruses to insert malicious code into executables?

Tags: security, executable

Executables are just text files that are interpreted by the operating system, so what is preventing viruses to just insert malicious text into executables files that will do malicious actions once interpreted ? Are executables obfuscated so we can't find a place that we will be sure will be executed once the executable is running ?

Comment: `Executables are just text files that are interpreted by the operating system`. Nope, not even remotely. text files only contain human readable ascii characters. executables contain machine code pertinent to the os

Comment: what I meant was that a text file is a succession of 0 and 1 delimited in the file system, an executable too is a succession of 0 and 1 delimited in the file system it's just that de 0 and 1 are interpreted in other way than a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executables are not text files. Apart from that, modifying executables is exactly what many viruses do or did. Nowadays, computers are better protected, for instance in DOS and older versions of Windows, you could just modify executables. In Windows Vista and up, most programs are inside the program files folder, and a normal user cannot modify files in those folders, until they acquired elevated rights. A malicious program ran by the user would also not be able to access those folders, unless it would know of a security breach in this protection system.

Comment: so softwares that refuse to be installed in program files are making security breach ?

Comment: Bluntly said, yes. More accurately: Software that is installed in an unprotected location is more vulnerable for infection, but still a virus that would infect that software would still not be able to infect software in Program Files, although possibly it doesn't have to. Mind that there are other ways for viruses and other malware to do their work than just editing executables. That's just one method.